# Is there any way how to open file from virtual machine's hdfs system in the Windows env?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform

Maybe my question is a bit stupid, but I want to access hdfs file on host Windows environment, specifically, in eclipse. Hadoop and all related stuff is installed on VirtualBox (used Hortonworks Sandbox env. With Centos OS). On virtual machine I can work with hdfs without issues, tried to access `hdfs://192.168.56.101:8020/user/root/vectors/dictionary.file-0`. Tried on eclipse to access this, but got a exception.

So, is there any way to do it? If it is possible, a example would be great to get.

Comment: Solved the problem. So thank you all :) Will post the answer after 8hours, due to newbie restrictions on stack.

Comment: What is the exception you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main cause of the problem was that system did not know who I am.
I was needed a client of hadoop, so the problem was solved by adding client dependency into pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And here is the working example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://192.168.56.101:8020");
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        Path pt = new Path("/user/root/vectors/dictionary.file-0");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(pt)));
        try {
            String line;
            line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```